# Apply Ks.test upon variables from multiple dataframes in a loop

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have the following code:

```
RW1_PD <- ks.test(df1$RWS, df2$RWS)

RW2_PD <- ks.test(df1$RWS, df3$RWS)

RW3_PD <- ks.test(df1$RWS, df4$RWS)
```

However I want to perform this neatly using a loop, I'm a bit new to R and I'm struggling to get this into loop format, or perhaps using `lapply` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the dataframes in a list and then use `lapply` -

```
list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

result <- lapply(list_df, function(x) 
             lapply(list_df, function(x, y) ks.test(x$RWS, y$RWS)))
```